# R markdown - including an svg image with tooltips generated using RSVGTipsDevice package

Tags: r, svg, knitr

I want to include an `svg` image in an `.Rmd` document. The svg is created using the `RSVGTipsDevice` package as I want the image to have some tooltips. The problem is that after the image has been included into the generated HTML document, the tooltips do not work anymore. Although they work properly when I open the svg in a browser ([link to image](http://www.gridhub.uni-bremen.de/public/pics/plot.svg), hover over red rectangle to see the tooltip).

http://www.gridhub.uni-bremen.de/public/pics/plot.svg

Here is the complete `.Rmd` code:

````
```{r}
library(RSVGTipsDevice)
devSVGTips("plot.svg", toolTipMode=1)
  plot(0, type="n")
  setSVGShapeToolTip("A rectangle","it is red")
  rect(.1,.1,.4,.6, col='red')
dev.off()
```

![alt text](plot.svg)
````

The question is: How can I make the tooltips work?

Comment: Replace the `![alt text](plot.svg)` part with `<embed src="plot.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />`

Comment: I think the knitr approach would use [hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks) to perform the necessary processing to ensure this is how it would be output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does my comment help? To be clear, the `![alt text](plot.svg)` portion becomes `<img src="plot.svg">` which is not a proper way to include svg. To prove this works, I've provided the [source](https://github.com/cpsievert/cpsievert.github.com/blob/master/stack/17641945/RSVGTipsDevice.Rmd) and its [output](http://cpsievert.github.io/stack/17641945/RSVGTipsDevice.html).

Comment: @Carson I am looking for a way to include an svg image in a pdf rendered by rmarkdown. Do you think this is possible... somehow... with your solution?